# How to implement a Non-CQS API in JavaScript for setting and getting options

Tags: javascript, api

I'm developing a library that provide some configuration options. Simplifing, imagine that:

```
let library() {
  let options = {
    optA: 'optA',
    optB: 'optB'
  };

  return {
    //Public API
    stuff1: ...,
    stuff2: ...
  };
};
```

This library it's used this way:

```
let libInstance = library();
libInstance.stuff1(...);
//Do stuff
libInstance.stuff2(...);
//Do more stuff
```

But also my idea is that you can also change the configuration options of the library. This would be the way:

```
libInstance.optA('new value for optA');
let optBValue = libInstance.optB();
console.log(optBValue);
//prints "optB"
```

So, if you call as a method the name of an option it works as a setter or a getter depending if the call is with or without arguments. My problem is that there is a lot of options and I think it has to be possible to achieve this without defining in the public API a method for every option, specially because all this methods would have a very similar behaviour.

Then, what i want is that when you call an undefined function in my library, it checks if there is an option with the name of the function, and if it exists, call the pertinent setter or getter. Only in the case that the function doesn't match with any option, an exception would be thrown.

Is this possible? How? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been investigating and I think it's not possible to do exactly what I wanted (that when you call an undefined function in my library, it checks if there is an option with the name of the function, and if it exists, call the pertinent setter or getter).

Instead I created this helper method to generate default accessors:

```
var generateAccessors = function generateAccessors(obj, api, exceptions) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (exceptions.indexOf(key) < 0 && !api[key]) {
        api[key] = function accessor(newValue) {
          if (arguments.length === 0) {
            return obj[key];
          } else {
            obj[key] = newValue;
            return api;
          }
        };
      }
    }
  }
};
```

`obj` is the input object, `api` the object where we want to create the accessors, and `exceptions` an array where we can list keys that will be ignored by the helper. Also, if a `key` is defined in the `api` object, it will be ignored too, so if you want a special accessor define it first in your `api` object and later call this generator.

A couple of comments about `accessor` function itself:

- Note that to determine if the accessor is called as a getter or a
  setter we check the `arguments` length. This lets set a variable with
  the value `undefined`, if it is provided explicetly.
- Note also that if the accessor is called as a setter it will return
  the `api` object. This provides [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) functionality.

As the moment I will mark this as the solution but if somebody knows a better solution I will be very glad to read it.